# c++ static template subclasses

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods

I have read about why `static virtual` methods don't make any sense - either the function is `virtual` so it can be overridden by an implementation, or it's `static` because the type is known at compile-time, and it can't be both. I'm wondering if there's a way to do what I'm trying:

I have the same basic structure for reading in some pre-configured values:

```
// in some header
template < typename TYPE >
class Reader {
public:
    static TYPE getValue() {
        static TYPE value;
        static SomeFileClass(filename, &value, sizeof(value));
        return value;
    }
};

class OneValue : public Reader<uint16_t> {
public:
    static const char* filename;
};
// and maybe OtherValue : public Reader<SomeUserType> {}; etc etc.

// in main.cpp, for example
const char* OneValue::filename = "onevalue.txt";
```

This, and various variations of this, fail. First it said `filename` wasn't declared in `Reader` which sounds reasonable; so then I declared a `static const char* filename` there, with the plan of intentionally shadowing `Reader::filename` with `OneValue::filename`, because when I use it later on, I will call `OneValue::getValue()` - I know the type when I'm calling it.

However, that doesn't work because `Reader::filename` isn't defined, but when I define it, it says template used without template parameters` which also sounds like a reasonable error, but now I'm out of ideas.

Is there a way to cleanly do what I want, without a lot of code copying? I'm open to completely new formulations, just want it to be clear and concise - the code above, while it has contrived names, is actually the entirety of the `Reader` class I was hoping to implement, so re-defining some `getValue()` in each derived class is more work than desired, since it would take probably more lines to derive-and-override than to just reimplement `getValue()` for each class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual solution to this kind of problem is [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template < typename TYPE, typename Derived >
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class Reader {
public:
    static TYPE getValue() {
        static TYPE value;
        static SomeFileClass(Derived::filename, &value, sizeof(value));
        //                   ^^^^^^^^^
        return value;
    }
};

class OneValue : public Reader<uint16_t, OneValue> {
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
// etc.
};
```

Comment: Ahh, I saw a mention of that in another question, but didn't fully understand it at first.

Comment: Now that makes more sense. Awesome, thanks, just what I needed!